# Pygame, cannot import sound

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame

i have tried extensively to fix this an i cannot find a single one that will fix this, any suggestions?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init
pygame.display.set_caption("hey press 1234567890-= and i'll press back!")

a_1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a1.mp3")
a_2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a2.mp3")
a_3 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a3.mp3")
a_4 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a4.mp3")
a_5 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a5.mp3")
a_6 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a6.mp3")
a_7 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a7.mp3")
a_8 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a8.mp3")
a_9 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a9.mp3")
a_10 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a10.mp3")
a_11 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a11.mp3")
a_12 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a12.mp3")

if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    a_1.Sound.play()
    if event.key == K_1:
        a_1.play()
```

and the error it comes back with is
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "\fs-03\14AColeman$\Documents\PYTHONFILES\wetransfer-5540b1    \MUSBOT.py", line 7, in 
        a_1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("a1.mp3")
    pygame.error: Unable to open file 'a1.mp3'

Comment: Try to convert one of the mp3 files into the .ogg format and test if it works with that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your problem is loading audio file or playing it?
If it's loading. Try just loading and playing a file from current folder your `python` script is and see if it plays.

If it loads and does not play, then try playing a `.wav` file as
`pygame` plays `.wav` file easily, so try with that before moving onto `mp3`.

If you do need to play `mp3` , try using following to see if it loads and plays properly before moving onto catching a keyboard event.

```
import pygame
from Tkinter import *

mp3 = "yourMP3file.mp3"
afile = mp3
root = Tk()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(afile)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation for pygame sound:

"The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV"

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound

I would recommend a different file format or convert what you have. occasionally mp3s will work, but it depends on the bit rate